# Design tab not Found Magento Admin

Tags: magento2, theme, store-view, design

I have created a custom theme and want to apply that theme
but when I go to *Store => Settings => Configuration => General* there isn't design tab in a *General* tab

Is there another way to create a store custom theme?

Please help me

Answer (score 4):

Design configuration after Magento 2.1.0 is found under **Content > Design (Configuration)**, where you can find theme configuration for website/store/store view.

[image: Design configuration]

Clicking on the configuration of website or store or store view, you can get the option to change the theme.

[image: theme configuration]

Answer (score 0):

It is moved in **Content > Design > Configuration** after Magento 2.1.

I have added doc [URL](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html) to know more about it.